# Stutter and track starts playing multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

Every once in a while when using Spotify player we encounter a stutter that lasts roughly ten seconds. While there are a few aspects that seem abnormal to me the most consistent sign that it is happening is that we hit the `didStartPlayingTrack` delegate method more than once even though we only told the player to play once. Does anyone have any ideas what could cause this to occur?

Important note: this is `spotify-ios-sdk version 0.21`

A sample of the logs:

```
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyTrackDelivered") // Last track ended
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyAudioDeliveryDone")
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyPause")
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged")
movePlayerPosition(_:completion:)[L:180]: seek successful to 0.842
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged")
13:13:50 audioStreaming(_:didStartPlayingTrack:)[L:377]: didStartPlayingTrack: Optional("So Far Away (Live) - Live")
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyTrackChanged")
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackEventAudioFlush")
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyPlay")
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged")
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged")
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyContextChanged")
13:14:01 audioStreaming(_:didStartPlayingTrack:)[L:377]: didStartPlayingTrack: Optional("So Far Away (Live) - Live")
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackNotifyTrackChanged")
audioStreaming(_:didSeekToPosition:)[L:474]: did seek to position: 0.001
audioStreaming(_:didReceive:withName:)[L:412]: didReceiveEvent: Optional("SPPlaybackEventAudioFlush")
```

Is there anyway to prevent this stutter from occuring?

**Update**

I've switched to version 25 and I am still encountering the issue. The one noticeable trait in the stutter logs that I have found is that on most starts of songs I do not get a `didSeekToPosition` delegate unless specifically requested; however when the stutter is encountered I see the following when stuttering begins:

```
audioStreaming(_:didStartPlayingTrack:)[L:377]: didStartPlayingTrack
audioStreaming(_:didSeekToPosition:)[L:474]: did seek to position: 0.001
```

Just to be clear, there is only one method that calls `playSpotifyUri`; however, this `didStartPlaying` delegate gets hit multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

The iOS SDK is now at version Beta 25, have you considered upgrading? I'd recommend doing that and seeing if it resolves your problem.

I'd need to see your specific implementation in order to debug.

Comment: Hi Arielle, I am actively looking at updating to 25 as an option, there are a few unrelated issues in 25 that are causing upgrading to be a little bit of a hassle. Unfortunately the problem happens infrequently enough that it is hard to recreate and know if 25 does not have the issue itself. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I've updated my sdk and while there are some great improvements in the sdk I am still encountering the stutter. I've updated my question.

Comment: @chasenyc Great - your updated logs help a bit. I'll see if I have some time to look into it.